# Retrieve uploaded image attibutes value from option tree theme options

Tags: theme-options, plugin-option-tree

I'm using option tree for my theme options page. But I can't retrieve uploaded images attribute like alternative text, description,caption etc.

How can I do that.

Comment: what does option tree store, an attachment ID?

Comment: Hello, #Milo ,                                                                                              Thank u for you quick replie.I'm a newbee.did you mean " 'class'       => 'ot-upload-attachment-id' "  to use. yes i did it.

Comment: no, I mean how is your option field storing the reference to an image? is it an attachment ID, or just a URL?

Comment: Sorry for late @Milo, I don't know exactly, I think it referencing just URL because I retrieved image src with just " $header_logo =  get_option_tree( 'header_logo', '', false ); " . How can I know what option field storing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this code in `index.php`

---

```
<img class="img-resposive" src="<?php 
    $logo=get_option_tree( 'logo','','true'); // return src of img
    $id_logo = get_attachment_id_from_src($logo); // This is custom  function for getting image id.
    $alt = get_post_meta($id_logo, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);// get alt="" from wordpress media.
    if ( function_exists( 'get_option_tree') ) : 
        if( get_option_tree( 'logo')) :             
            $logo;  
        else:
             echo bloginfo('template_directory') .'/assets/images/logo_vp.png'; // else if option is empty get this image.
        endif;  
    endif;  
?>" alt="<?php echo $alt; ?>"/>
```

Put this function code in `functions.php`

```
//get id from image source
function get_attachment_id_from_src ($image_src) {
    global $wpdb;
    $query = "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE guid='$image_src'";
    $id = $wpdb->get_var($query);
    return $id;
}
```

---

This code is tested. Working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct answer for optiontree 2.4+

https://github.com/valendesigns/option-tree/issues/112

**Note**

```
'class'       => 'ot-upload-attachment-id',
```

**Example:**

```
array(
  'id'          => 'demo_upload_attachment_id',
  'label'       => __( 'Upload Attachment ID', 'option-tree-theme' ),
  'desc'        => sprintf( __( 'The Upload option type can also be saved as an attachment ID by adding %s to the class attribute.', 'option-tree-theme' ), '<code>ot-upload-attachment-id</code>' ),
  'std'         => '',
  'type'        => 'upload',
  'section'     => 'option_types',
  'rows'        => '',
  'post_type'   => '',
  'taxonomy'    => '',
  'min_max_step'=> '',
  'class'       => 'ot-upload-attachment-id',
  'condition'   => '',
  'operator'    => 'and'
)
```